# getting the latest data about covid-19 pandemic per country with a Wikidata SPARQL query

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I'm trying to extract some of the latest data about covid-19 pandemic statistics (number of cases, recoveries, point in time) per country from Wikidata using this SPARQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?COVID19_loc ?COVID19_locLabel ?countryLabel ?cases ?timeC ?recoveries ?timeR {  
    ?pandemic wdt:P1269 wd:Q81068910;
    FILTER ( ?pandemic in ( wd:Q83741704)).
    ?pandemic wdt:P527 ?COVID19_loc.
    ?COVID19_loc wdt:P17 ?country.
    ?COVID19_loc wdt:P1603 ?cases.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?COVID19_loc wdt:P1603/wdt:P585 ?timeC_Other FILTER ( ?timeC_Other > ?timeC)}.
    ?COVID19_loc wdt:P8010 ?recoveries.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?COVID19_loc wdt:P8010/wdt:P585 ?timeR_Other FILTER ( ?timeR_Other > ?timeR)}.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". } }
```

The thing is I'm getting multiples cases and recoveries results instead of the latest of them only, also timeC and timeR don't return a thing!

Comment: Same question on SO (with screenshot): [extracting covid-19 pandemic most recent data per country using a Wikidata SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74374830/19579546)